# Recursive Python function translation to Javascript not working, issue with arrays

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, math, recursion

I want to translate a Python program (which solves a certain basic combinatorial problem) to Javascript. The goal is to evaluate *my_function(200, [1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200])*, and the result is that the Python program returns the correct answer (~70k), but my attempted Javascript translation returns a wrong answer (~60k).

The function *my_function* is defined recursively, and in particular the second input, a list, is truncated in the recursion step (see second-to-last line of code). I may not have handled this well in the JS version.

**Python function:**

```
import math

coin_sizes = [1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200]

def my_function(amount, coins_list):
    if amount == 0:
        return 1
    elif len(coins_list) == 0:
        return 0
    elif len(coins_list) == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        top_coin = coins_list[-1]
        d = math.floor(amount/top_coin)
        total = 0
        for i in range(0,d+1):
            total += my_function(amount - i*top_coin, coins_list[:-1])
        return total
```

**Javascript function:**

```
var coin_sizes = [1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200];

var sublist = function(mylist) {
    var new_list = Array(mylist.length-1);
    for (var i = 0; i < mylist.length-1; i++){
        new_list[i] = mylist[i];
    }
    return new_list
};

var my_function = function(amount, coins_list) {
    if (amount == 0) return 1;
    else if (coins_list.length == 0) return 0;
    else if (coins_list.length == 1) return 1;
    else {
        var top_coin = coins_list[(coins_list.length-1)];
        d = Math.floor(amount/top_coin);
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < d+1; i++) {
        total += my_function(amount - i*top_coin, sublist(coins_list));
        };
        return total;
    };
};
```

I tried writing a similar program in Java, but got too many stack overflow errors.

**Question:** What's going on? Why do I get the wrong answer, and is there a better way to translate this Python program to Javascript?

Note: The original combinatorial problem can be solved dynamically/without recursion, and then I would have no problem translating it to Javascript. I want to learn how to write something similar to the Python function above.

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out where it goes wrong, but I have seen that *negative* values for `amount` get passed to the JS version, but not the python version, when called with amount=20. Gotta be something with the for loop and the subtracting i*top_coin that is diverging in the JS impl...

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss to declare `d`.

BTW, you could use exit early paradigm `if ... return ...` and go on without `else` and for the last block, you need to declare all variables, because if not, the variable is global and the value changes with the recursive call.

Another hint, after block statements `{ ... }`, like with `for` or `else`, you need no semicolon.

And finaly, you could use [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) for getting a copy from start until end - 1 by using `-1` as *to* parameter (the second one).

```js
var coin_sizes = [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200],
    sublist = function(mylist) {
        return mylist.slice(0, -1);
    },
    my_function = function(amount, coins_list) {
        if (amount == 0) return 1;
        if (coins_list.length == 0) return 0;
        if (coins_list.length == 1) return 1;
        var top_coin = coins_list[(coins_list.length - 1)],
            d = Math.floor(amount / top_coin),
            total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < d + 1; i++) {
            total += my_function(amount - i * top_coin, sublist(coins_list));
        }
        return total;
    };

console.log(my_function(200, [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200]));
```